# EasyNetQ is not acknowledging received messages

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, easynetq

After connecting and receiving messages from RabbitMQ they are not being removed from the queue.

Every time I connect I receive the same messages, and only one.

```
using(bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost"))
{
    bus.Receive<MyMessage>("my-queue", message => Console.WriteLine("MyMessage: {0}", message.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in [Connecting to RabbitMQ](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Connecting-to-RabbitMQ), create a single instance of the `Bus` and use it in the whole application.

I have identified the following procedures:

1. Create an instance of the Bus that is application-wide
2. Optionally, add it as a Singleton in the dependency injection
3. Start listening to messages
4. Register to dispose the Bus once the application shuts down

This is the simplified `Startup.cs` with the relevant snippets as demo code:

```
public class Startup
{

    // This will be your application instance
    IBus bus;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {  
        // Create, assign the Bus, and add it as Singleton to your application
        bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost");
        // now you can easyly inject in your components
        services.AddSingleton(bus);
    }

    public void Configure(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        // Start receiving messages from the queue
        bus.Receive<MyMessage>("my-queue", message => Console.WriteLine("MyMessage: {0}", message.Text));

        // Hook your custom shutdown the the lifecycle
        lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    }
    private void OnShutdown()
    {
        // Dispose the Bus
        bus.Dispose();
    }
}
```